# How to change D3 Dimple tooltips with chart data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I realize this may be my misunderstanding of series with Dimple, but I can't figure out how to change  D3 Dimple tooltips ?

Say I have data like this:

```
var data = [{"date":"01-02-2010","cost":"3796"},{"date":"01-03-2010","cost":"2699"},{"date":"01-04-2010","cost":"4588"}];
```

and when move to the bubble will show the tooltip

```
date:01-02-2010
cost:3796
cost:3.8k
```

but i want to show the tooltip  like

```
date:01-02-2010
cost:3796
```

I think the problem is

```
  y.tickFormat = ',.0f';    
  myChart.addColorAxis(ycord, ["green", "yellow", "red"]);
```

but I don't know how to modify the tooltip

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewarnier/Ra2xS/332/

Any suggestions? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to your desire output. But I just want to point out, that I used dimple v2.2.0 version.

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/333/)

```
s.getTooltipText = function (e) {
            return [
                "date : " + e.cx + "",
                "value : " + e.cy + ""
            ];
        };
```

As you can see you can tweak around and make anything shown as tooltip. I hope this hels

Answer (score 1):

Mahmut's answer is correct, in that you can create whichever custom tooltip you like, however you can also remove the extra cost from the tooltip a different way.

Dimple's default tooltip logic is pretty simple.  It retrieves the value from the series and each connected axis and includes them all in the tooltip.  As a slight refinement it checks if any of the rows in the tooltip are identical and removes the duplicates.  Here you have hit an unusual case where the same metric is being provided by the colour axis and the y axis but you have applied a tick format to y so the strings are different.

The solution is to apply the same tick format to the colour axis:

```
var c = myChart.addColorAxis(ycord, ["green", "yellow", "red"]); 
c.tickFormat = ',.0f';
```

It's a little odd but it means both axes report matching strings and the duplication is removed.